# After I overrode a block template for a primary links, block-edit-link doesn't show anymore...?

Tags: blocks, theming

I just created **block-menu-primary-links.tpl.php** file in the root of my theme, in order to strip off some default structures I have for other blocks, but now that I did that, *block-edit-link* which was displaying itself by default on hover, doesn't appear anymore. It's not that I want it to back, but I just wonder why did it go away and how can I control it?

**UPDATE**:

Here is what I have in my **block-menu-primary-links.tpl.php**:

```
<div id="block-menu-primary-links">
    <?php echo $block->content; ?>
</div>
```

When I inspect html structure after it is rendered I see that contextual links are in there, but hidden and obviously block has lost something that made the logic tick.

Comment: How did you override the template? If the primary links are rendered as a block then the contextual links will appear. If you use some other method to render the menu without putting it in a block with block markup then the links will not show.

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry for being not specific, I'm still not touching the Drupal ground.

Comment: For whatever reason, they are in my case, if by contextual links we both understand a little menu with actions to edit and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, tracked down the reason - every block requires to have a *className* of **block**:

```
<div id="block-menu-primary-links" class="block">
    <?php echo $block->content; ?>
</div>
```

Once I added this, contextual links regained the functionality. Still not sure where it comes from though, or if it's the only thing sufficient in all cases.